# Populating A Dropdown With Ajax

Tags: cakephp-1.3

I am populating a dropdown successfully with some code I found online. My problem is this, I need the dropdown to also have another option of "Other". and by selecting Other i want to display text box. How would I modify the script below to achieve this?and

```
<?php
$option = array();
foreach($rsCity as $key=>$value) {
  $option[$value['City']['id']] = $value['City']['name'];
}
echo $this->Form->input('register.CityID', array(
  'options'=>$option,
  'empty' => 'Select',
  'label'=>false,
  'selected'=>'',
  'style'=>'width:150px',
  'div'=>false
));
?>
```

thnx

Answer (score 0):

YOu are best off doing this in the browser, eg with Jquery.

add in the option of other to the array of options.

Watch for the select box to change, and if the value is other, show the text box to type in the extra info.

so something like

```
if($(this).attr('value') === 'Other'){
    $('#other').show('slow');
}
```